# Python Selenium Chromedriver, Not able to detect a refresh

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently trying to detect when a website redirects me (trying to detect a refresh)

Currently, I'm using

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
```

However, it is pretty inaccurate because sometimes you are on the page before redirect for 1-10 seconds and the following code above would detect that page, not the new page it is redirecting me to. Is there a way to detect when they redirect/forward you to another page? I want to be as efficient as possible, so webdriverwait to wait for an element to load is not viable.